# Prevent double active function on live table upload

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table with contenteditable value, when i change value an ajax action will update value for DB.
the problem is when clicking on a box and then on another immediately after the alert continues to appear without being able to do anything else.
Is there a way to prevent the other clicks function once started?

Code JS:

```
function showEdit(editableObj) {
  $(editableObj).css("background", "#FFF");
}

function saveToDatabase(editableObj, column, id) {
  var isGood = confirm('Are you sure?');
  if (isGood) {

    $(editableObj).css("background", "#FFF url(./img/loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
      url: "saveedit.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: 'column=' + column + '&editval=' + editableObj.innerHTML + '&id=' + id,
      success: function(data) {
        $(editableObj).css("background", "#FDFDFD");
      }
    });
    //  }
  } else {
    alert('Abort');
  }
}
```

Php table:

```
echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this, \'nameDB\', \''.$res2['valuefromDB'].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">' .$res2['valuefromDB'] .'</td>';
```

Comment: It is possible to prevent functions from firing. Please describe your perfect scenario of how your code should work. Right now it opens the `confirm` prompt every time you move focus, correct?

Comment: Now when i click to blank part of page confirm alert will appear and after confirm will upload to DB(all work correctly). But if i press on another td cell confirm is bugged and continue to appear without possible to cancel or process.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier you have any tips for me? and i confirm function work every time user move focus

Comment: Personally, I would suggest that you don't use the `onblur` event to trigger the prompt. Instead create a button on which you manually trigger the prompt and save the entire table.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier is a good idea but if the user try to change all row i think the script will fail. onblur is for change every row individually

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, simple first step:

```
echo '<td contenteditable="false"  //false and not true this time
```

At the function ShowEdit:

```
function showEdit(editableObj) {
  editableObj.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
  editableObj.focus(); //focus directly when change contenteditable
}
```

I simple add editable true only to td i edit so alert will not trigger if user blur in another td.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flag to prevent activation:

```
var saveEnabled = true; // Only let you save when this is true
function saveToDatabase(editableObj, column, id) {
  if (!saveEnabled) return; // If saveEnabled is false do not continue
  saveEnabled = false;
  var isGood = confirm('Are you sure?');
  if (isGood) {
    $(editableObj).css("background", "#FFF url(./img/loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
      url: "saveedit.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: 'column=' + column + '&editval=' + editableObj.innerHTML + '&id=' + id,
      complete: function(data) { // Errors should be handled before this
        $(editableObj).css("background", "#FDFDFD");
        saveEnabled = true;
      }
    });
    //  }
  } else {
    alert('Abort');
    saveEnabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Now for example the abort button doesn't work, when you click the alert continue to appear. But now if i press continue work.

Comment: Abort? Continue? I dont see this in the original question.

Comment: Yes i mean the alert (YES/NO result by alert)

Comment: Can you rephrase? I can't understand

Comment: Simple as you can see on my code, when onblur change(Like click out of table) an alert appear for confirm or abort the operation.  The problem in my first post was when I left the TD by clicking another TD alert is triggered and i can't continue or abort with alert, else if i click in the "blank page" all work. with your code if i click another TD alert work only with continue and not with abort.