# Data entered into Bootstrap editable table sent to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap editable table with add, edit, and delete options. I made a PHP connection so that the data in the table is fetched from my database.

I want to add the option that when data is entered or a row is edited or deleted these changes happen in database too not only on website.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed  text-center" id="DyanmicTable">
    <tr>
      <th>row 1</th>
      <th>row 2</th>
      <th>row 3</th>
      <th>row 4</th>
      <th>row 5</th>
      <th class="text-center">
      <button id="addNewRow" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add New Row</button>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $rows['row 1'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['row 2'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['row 3'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['row 4'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['row 5'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </table>
```

This is the table I am using.

Comment: What did you try so far to achieve your expected result?

Comment: I tried searching all over and edting then deleting mostly because most of the code is too complicated for me to understand and edit to make it work

Comment: I would suggest starting reading ```ajax```.

Comment: [My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264243/prevent-double-active-function-on-live-table-upload), here you can find an example

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. I'll try to rephrase my question better:
I have three buttons, one for adding one for editing and one for deleting I want each one to do what it's meant to.